# IE behaves badly with javascript

Tags: javascript, css, internet-explorer

I customize theme I bought and it behaves very weird in IE. :) I recorded problem and posted on YT so you can see it:

http://youtu.be/uG36_1WTt-k

Web site is temporary on http://test.emreza.com/?cat=4 so you can see live what is problem. I assume that  there is some kind of problem with javascript and css. Also when I toggle compatibility mode in IE everything works just fine.

Any idea what can I do with that?

Edit: As I figured that it is not javascript here is css I used. it is mostly from theme but I added some stuff:

```
    /*********************************************************************************************

Theme Name: Cafe Elements
Theme URI: http://www.press75.com/
Description: Designed by Jason Schuller
Version: 2.1.4
Author: Press75.com
Author URI: http://www.press75.com/

**********************************************************************************************

Designed and Built by Jason Schuller - theSevenFive.com

CSS, XHTML and Design Files are all Copyright 2007-2010 Circa75 Media, LLC

Be inspired, but please don't steal :)

**********************************************************************************************

0.  CSS Reset  -------------------------  All Theme Files
1.  Basic Setup  -----------------------  All Theme Files
2.  Header and Menu Styles  ------------  header.php
3.  Main Content Containers  -----------  home.php, index.php, single.php, page.php
4.  Carousel Styles  -------------------  home.php
5.  Business Information  --------------  home.php
6.  Category, Archive and Search Pages -  index.php
7.  Post Content Styles ----------------  index.php, single.php, page.php
8.  Post Comment Styles ----------------  single.php
9.  Sidebar and Widgets  ---------------  sidebar.php
10. Footer Styles  ---------------------  footer.php

**********************************************************************************************/


/********************************************************************************************* 

0. CSS Reset  -------------------------  All Theme Files

*********************************************************************************************/
body, div, dl, dt, dd, ul, ol, li, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, pre, form, fieldset, input, textarea, p, blockquote, th, td {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}

table {
border-collapse: collapse;
border-spacing: 0;
}

fieldset, img {border: 0;}

address, caption, cite, code, dfn, em, strong, th, var {
font-style: normal;
font-weight: normal;
}

ol, ul {list-style: none;}
caption, th {text-align: left;}

h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
font-size: 100%;
font-weight: normal;
}

q:before, q:after {content: '';}
abbr, acronym {border: 0;}


/*********************************************************************************************

1. Basic Setup  -----------------------  All Theme Files

*********************************************************************************************/
body {
background: #323232 url(images/brck.jpg) repeat fixed;
width: auto;
height: auto;
font-family: Arial, Helvetica, Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
font-size: 14px;
line-height: 18px;
color: #000000;
}

h1, h1 a:link, h1 a:visited { /* For the Logo */
color: #FFFFFF;
font-size: 40px;
font-weight: normal;
margin: 0 0 5px 0;
}

h2, h2 a:link, h2 a:visited {
color: #B74718;
font-size: 18px;
font-weight: normal;
margin: 0 0 5px 0;
}

h3, h3 a:link, h3 a:visited {
color: #B74718;
font-size: 18px;
font-weight: normal;
margin: 0 0 5px 0;
}

h4 {
color: #B74718;
font-size: 14px;
font-weight: normal;
margin: 0 0 2px 0;
}

h2 a:hover, h3 a:hover, h4 a:hover {
color: #9F3F16;
}

blockquote {
padding: 0 0 0 15px;
font-style: italic;
border-left: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
}

strong {font-weight: bold;}

a:link, a:visited {
color: #003366;
}

a:hover {
color: #FFFFFF;
}

abbr,acronym {
border-bottom: 1px dotted;
cursor: help;
} 

em {font-style: italic;}
ol,ul {margin: 0;}
ol li {list-style: decimal outside;}
ul li {list-style: none;}

th,td {
border: 1px solid;
padding: 8px;
}

th {
font-weight:bold;
text-align:center;
}

caption {
margin-bottom: 8px;
text-align: center;
}

p,fieldset,table {margin-bottom: 10px;}
a:link, a:visited {text-decoration: none;}

:focus {
outline: 0;
}

.alignleft {
float: left;
}

.alignright {
float: right;
}

#logotip {
position: absolute;
top: 0px;
z-index: 10000000;
}

#social {
position: fixed;
left: -10px;
top: 200px;
}

/*********************************************************************************************

2. Header and Menu Styles  ---------------------  header.php

*********************************************************************************************/
#header {
width: 100%;
float: left;
height: 142px;
}

#header-inside {
width: 960px;
margin: 0px auto;
padding: 40px 0 10px 0;
overflow: hidden;
}

#navigation {
background: url(images/navigation.png) center no-repeat;
width: 100%;
float: left;
font-family: "Lobster", arial, sans-serif;
font-size: 18px;
}

.navigation-inside {
width: 960px;
margin: 0px auto;
}

p.site-text {
color: #B74718;
float: left;
margin: 0;
padding: 0 0 20px 0;
}

.menu, .menu * { /* SuperFish Menu Styles */
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
list-style: none;
}

.menu {
float: right;
}

.menu a {
display: block;
position: relative;
}

.menu a, .menu a:visited  {
color: #D43E39;
}

.menu a:hover  {
color: #0B3B0B;
text-decoration:underline;
background-color:#ffffff;
}

.menu ul li {
width: 100%;
}

.menu ul {
position: absolute;
top: -15000px;
width: 160px; /* Left Offset of Sub-Menus Need to Match */
}

.menu li:hover ul, 
.menu li.sfHover ul {
left: -15px;
top: 22px; /* Match Top UL List Item Height */
z-index: 10000;
}

ul.menu li:hover li ul, 
ul.menu li.sfHover li ul {
top: -15000px;
}

ul.menu li li:hover ul, 
ul.menu li li.sfHover ul {
left: 160px; /* Match ul width. */
top: 0;
}

ul.menu li li:hover li ul, 
ul.menu li li.sfHover li ul {
top: -15000px;
}

ul.menu li li li:hover ul, 
ul.menu li li li.sfHover ul {
left: 160px; /* Match ul Width. */
top: 0;
}

.menu li {
float: left;
position: relative;
margin: 0 0 0 10px;
padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
}

.menu li:hover {
background-color:#ffffff;
visibility: inherit; /* Fixes IE7 Sticky Bug */
}

.menu li ul {
background: #FFFFFF;
font-size: 14px;
width: 125px;
margin: 10px 0 0 0;
padding: 10px 40px 10px 15px;
}

.menu li ul a:link, .menu li ul a:visited {
color: #555555;
}

.menu li ul a:hover {
color: #888888;
}

.menu li ul li:hover {
background: none;
}

.menu li li {
background: none;
margin: 0 0 0 0;
padding: 0 0 0 0;
text-transform: none;
}

.menu li li ul {
background: #FFFFFF;
margin: -10px 0 0 -50px;
}

.selected, .current-cat, .current_page_item {
background-color:#ffffff;
color: #D43E39;
text-decoration:underline;
}


/*********************************************************************************************

3. Main Content Containers  -----------  home.php, index.php, single.php, page.php

*********************************************************************************************/
#content {
width: 100%;
float: left;
}

#content-inside {
background: url(images/bg1.png) repeat;
width: 920px;
margin: 0px auto;
padding: 20px 20px 0 20px;
margin-bottom: 20px;
overflow: hidden;
}

#fresh {
position: relative;
z-index: 1000000;
}
#fresh-in {
position: absolute;
top: 290px;
left: -16px;
z-index: 1000000;
}

#posts {
width: 710px;
float: left;
}

#posts-page {
width: 710px;
float: left;
}

#posts-full {
width: 940px;
float: left;
padding: 0 20px 0 0;
}

#paginate {
background: #FFFFFF;
color: #666666;
font-size: 12px;
float: left;
margin: 0 0 20px 0;
padding: 1px 8px 1px 8px;
}

#paginate a {
color: #666666;
font-weight: bold;
}


/*********************************************************************************************

4. Carousel Styles  -------------------  home.php

*********************************************************************************************/
#featured-posts {
width: 370px;
height: 370px;
float: left;
margin: 0 0 20px 0;
}

.coda-slider, .coda-slider .panel {
background: url(images/featuredbck.png);
width: 370px;
height: 370px;
} 

.coda-slider-wrapper.arrows .coda-slider, .coda-slider-wrapper.arrows .coda-slider .panel {
width: 370px;
}

#coda-nav {
width: 370px;
position: relative;
}

.coda-nav-left a {
background: url(images/left.png) 0 0;
position: absolute;
width: 58px;
height: 102px;
top: 132px;
left: 0;
z-index: 500000;
}

.coda-nav-left a:hover {
background: url(images/left.png) 0 -102px;
}

.coda-nav-right a {
background: url(images/right.png) 0 0;
position: absolute;
width: 58px;
height: 102px;
top: 132px;
right: 5px;
z-index: 500000;
}

.coda-nav-right a:hover {
background: url(images/right.png) 0 -102px;
}

.coda-slider-wrapper {
clear: both;
overflow: auto;
}

.coda-slider {
float: left;
overflow: hidden;
position: relative;
}

.coda-slider .panel {
display: block;
float: left;
}

.coda-slider .panel-container {
position: relative;
}

.featured-post {
color: #B7B7B7;
width: 350px;
height: 350px;
margin: 10px 0 0 10px;
}

.attachment-featured {
float: left;
}


/*********************************************************************************************

5. Business Information  --------------  home.php

*********************************************************************************************/
#welcome {
width: 300px;
float: left;
margin: 20px 20px 20px 20px;
}

#contact {
background: url(images/contact.png) top left no-repeat;
padding: 0 0 0 40px;
margin: 0 0 20px 0;
}

#hours {
background: url(images/hours.png) top left no-repeat;
padding: 0 0 0 40px;
margin: 0 0 20px 0;
}

#address {
background: url(images/location.png) top left no-repeat;
padding: 0 0 0 40px;
margin: 0 0 20px 0;
}

.number, .primary-days, .secondary-days, .street {
font-size: 18px;
font-family: "Lobster", arial, sans-serif;
color: #B74718;
}

.primary-hours {
margin-bottom: 10px;
}


/*********************************************************************************************

6. Category, Archive and Search Pages -  index.php

*********************************************************************************************/
.post-item {
width: 680px;
float: left;
margin: 0 0 20px 0;
}

.post-thumbnail {
background: url(images/featuredbck.png);
width: 370px;
height: 370px;
float: left;
margin: 0 20px 0 0;
}

.post-thumbnail img {
padding: 10px;
}

.posted-in {
float: left;
}

.posted-in a {
background: #FFFFFF;
color: #666666;
font-size: 12px;
margin: 0 10px 0 0;
padding: 2px 8px 2px 8px;
}

.posted-in li {
margin: 0 0 10px 0;
}


/*********************************************************************************************

7. Post Content Styles ----------------  index.php, single.php, page.php

*********************************************************************************************/
.single-post-item {
margin: 0;
}

.post-details {
width: 680px;
float: left;
margin: 0 0 20px 0;
}

ul.post-meta {
margin: 0;
}

.post-meta-post li {
padding-left: 0;
}

.post-content {
width: 680px;
float: left;
}

.post-content a {
text-decoration: underline;
}

.post-content-full { /* Full Width Pages */
width: 920px;
}

.post-content ul {
margin: 0 0 15px 15px;
}

.post-content ul li {
list-style: disc;
}

.post-content ol {
margin: 0 0 15px 20px;
}

p img {
padding: 0;
max-width: 100%;
}

.wp-caption {
background: #F6F6F6;
text-align: center;
padding: 10px 5px 5px 5px;
color: #555555;
}

.alignleft {
margin: 5px 20px 20px 0;
}

.alignright {
margin: 5px 0 20px 20px;
}

.wp-caption img {
padding: 0;
margin: 0 0 5px;
}

.wp-caption-text {
margin: 10px 0 0;
padding: 0;
}

.wp-caption .wp-caption-text, .wp-caption .wp-caption-dd {
font-size: 12px !important;
text-align: center; 
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}

img.centered {
display: block;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
}

img.alignright {
float: right;
padding: 5px;
margin: 0 0 2px 15px;
}

img.alignleft {
float: left;
padding: 5px;
margin: 0 15px 2px 0;
}

h4.not-here {
font-size: 14px;
}


/*********************************************************************************************

8. Post Comment Styles ----------------  single.php

*********************************************************************************************/
#comments {
width: 670px;
float: left;
padding: 0 20px 0 0;
}

#comments-meta p {
margin: 0;
padding: 5px 0 5px 0;
}

#comments ol {
margin: 0 0 20px 0;
}

#comments ol li {
list-style: none;
}

ol.commentlist li {
background: url(images/comment.png) top left no-repeat;
padding: 10px 0 0 32px;
margin: 20px 0 20px 0;
}

ol.commentlist li.alt {
background: url(images/comment.png) top left no-repeat;
padding: 10px 0 0 32px;
margin: 20px 0 20px 0;
}

ol.commentlist li ul.children { 
list-style: none; 
text-indent: 0; 
}

ol.commentlist li ul.children li {
background: url(images/comment.png) top left no-repeat;
padding: 10px 0 0 32px;
margin: 20px 0 20px 0;
}

ol.commentlist li ul.children li.alt {
background: url(images/comment.png) top left no-repeat;
padding: 10px 0 0 32px;
margin: 20px 0 20px 0;
}

.comment-meta {
font-size: 11px;
margin: 0 0 12px 0;
}

.comment-meta a {
color: #888888; 
}

span.says {
display: none;
}

.comment-author {
font-size: 14px;
}

.avatar {
background: url(images/avatar-bg.png) repeat;
float: right;
margin: -8px 0 20px 20px;
padding: 8px;
}

div.reply {
font-size: 11px;
}

div.reply a {
background: #FFFFFF;
color: #555555;
padding: 2px 8px 3px 8px;
}

.cancel-comment-reply a {
display: none;
}

#respond {
width: 100%;
padding: 20px 0 34px 5px;
}

#author, #email, #url, #comment {
background: url(images/fields-bg.png) repeat;
border: none;
font-family: Arial, Helvetica, Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
font-size: 12px;
line-height: 18px;
color: #CCCCCC;
padding: 6px 10px 6px 10px;
}

#comment {
width: 98%;
max-width: 645px;
}

input#submit {
background: #FFFFFF;
border: none;
font-family: Arial, Helvetica, Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
font-weight: normal;
font-size: 12px;
color: #555555;
float: left;
text-align: center;
margin: 0 0 25px 0;
padding: 3px 10px 3px 10px;
cursor: pointer;
}


/*********************************************************************************************

9. Sidebar and Widgets  ---------------  sidebar.php

*********************************************************************************************/
#sidebar {
width: 210px;
float: left;
}

.widget  {
width: 210px;
float: left;
margin: 5px 0 10px 0;
}

#featured-categories img {
background: #FFFFFF;
float: left;
margin: 0 10px 0 0;
padding: 5px;
}

#featured-categories h3 {
font-size: 14px;
margin: 0;
}

#featured-categories p {
font-size: 12px;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}

.featured-category {
width: 210px;
float: left;
margin: 0 0 10px 0;
}


/*********************************************************************************************

10. Footer Styles  ---------------------  footer.php

*********************************************************************************************/
#footer {
width: 100%;
float: left;
}

#footer-inside {
width: 960px;
margin: 0px auto;
}

#featured-categories-footer {
background: url(images/bg1.png) repeat;
width: 960px;
float: left;
margin: 0 0 0 0;
padding: 20px 0 20px 0;
}

#featured-categories-footer img {
background: #128262;
float: left;
margin: 0 15px 0 0;
padding: 8px;
}

#featured-categories-infooter img {
background: #FFFFFF;
float: left;
margin: 0 0 0 10px;
padding: 8px;
}

#featured-categories-footer p {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}

.featured-category-footer {
width: 250px;
float: right;
margin: 0 0 0 0;
padding: 0 10px 0 0;
}

#footer-content {
background: url(images/footercont.png);
width: 960px;
height: 31px;
float: left;
padding: 0 0 0 0;
}

#footer-content h3 {
font-size: 18px;
color: #B74718;
}

#footer-content p {
color: #FFFFFF;
}

#footer-content a {
color: #FFFFFF;
}

#footer-content a:hover {
color: #CCCCCC;
}
```

Comment: Could you post some code?

Comment: doesn't seem to belong java.

Comment: always research before you buy.. also posting links to the problem wont help us solve it

Comment: I only see this problem on IE7 are you getting it on other versions?

Comment: Well I figured that it is not problem with javascript. It's same java script used on demo website http://press75.com/view/cafe-elements/ and it is working in IE without problem. It is not something I need to solve right now but I'm definitely curious what is issue.I'll try to change css code to see where is problem. Also problem is manifested on IE 10 also as seen on video.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out what is problem. I used [IE Tester](http://www.my-debugbar.com/wiki/IETester/HomePage) for that. When I comment part of code

```
.posted-in {
float: left;
}
```

everything works just fine. Problem is that I don't understand why was that a problem.